# HTML change value of input Element, when value element already empty existing

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

Hello i want to fill out an input Element.

```
<input id="cardpan" type="text" data-style="height: 31px; width: 215px; font-size: 15px; background: #fff; padding: 0 4px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05);" value="" autocomplete="off" style="height: 31px; width: 215px; font-size: 15px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 1px 1px 3px inset;">
```

Now when i try this:

```
const ccnumber = document.querySelector('#cardpan input[type = text]');
ccnumber.value = '213123132';
```

In the console I get the output: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ccnumber' has already been declared.
Using puppeteer (headless chrome) it just doesnt fill out anything.

How can i do this? Is this because the value has already been declared as value=" "?

Thanks for any help :)
[image: I added a picture of the site, including the code.]

Comment: The element is inside an iframe. You need to use the document of this iframe, not the document of the top window. If you already use it, maybe it is worth providing more code.

Comment: Ahh no, i dont. Sorry I started with this a few days ago, Im still learning. How do i select a element (in this case input field) within an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it:

```
 const elementHandle = await page.$('span#cardpan iframe');
 const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
 await frame.evaluate(() => {
   const mach = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
   mach.value = '9999999999999';
             
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`const ccnumber = document.querySelector('#cardpan'); ccnumber.value = '213123132';`
try that?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the page, including the HTML code, where Im trying to insert the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find an iframe first and then use it in evaluation. Something like this:

```js
const frame = page.frames().find(
  f => f.url().startsWith('https://secure.pay1.de/')
);

await frame.evaluate(() => {
  const ccnumber = document.querySelector('#cardpan');
  ccnumber.value = '213123132';
});
```

Comment: The problem is, every single input field has a seperate iframe. So there are multiple iframes, thats why your solution istnt working. (My fault, case u couldnt see this on the screenshot, sorry.) If you want to reproduce this, go to notebooksbilliger.de and try to checkout a random product, select credit card payment and on the last step you get to this window.

Comment: I tried this now: `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1])`. My code looks like this: `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1];
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("cardpan");
await page.waitForSelector(elmnt);
await frame.evaluate(() => {
elmnt.value = '213123132'} `but its still not working...

Comment: You are mixing puppeteer and browser code. `document.getElementsByTagName` is available in the browser context only, while `page.waitForSelector` in puppeteer context only. Also, `document.getElementById` returns DOM element, while `page.waitForSelector` needs string.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. Makes sense. Is there a oppertunity to select a specific iframe element? because there are mulitple starting with ('https://secure.pay1.de/')

Comment: Tried this: 
`const elementHandle = await page.$('span#cardpan iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.evaluate(() => {
 const mach = document.querySelector('input[id="cardpan"]');
 mach.value = '9999999999999';
  });` not working